# DNN 6 Hide Retrieve password in Login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I want to remove/hide Retrieve Password link in the Login Form , i disabled its function from web.config but client still wants me to remove it from the Form any idea how can i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is currently a way to remove it other than to hide it with styles:

```
.dnnLoginActions {display:none;}
```